# Windows 10/Ubuntu boot failure

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, grub

I have a setup capable of dual-booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04, which has worked fine for just under a year. Some time since my last windows boot (~1 month ago), something has changed causing Windows to no longer be able to boot. The error message info given by Windows boot manager (which sometimes appears when I attempt to boot to Windows, sometimes not) is, 'The Boot Configuration Data for your PC is missing or contains errors.' The suggested action is to insert the installation media (USB) and use the repair utility. The Ubuntu installation boots and works fine.

Windows 10 is housed on a 256GB SSD and is aware of a 120GB SSD used for further storage. Ubuntu is located on a 1TB HDD. Windows 10 was installed first and Ubuntu added later. At startup, GNU GRUB is used to select which OS to load.

Is the dual-boot capable setup going to be an issue for the Windows repair utility? If I'm forced to reinstall, will GRUB still be loaded before either of the operating systems? If so, will it still be aware of both Ubuntu and the (hopefully) now-working Windows?

Honestly, I'm not all that savvy at this level, and the last thing I want to do is accidentally render both operating systems useless.

Comment: Do you know if you got some type of Windows Update recently? The last time you were using your PC, was it booted into Windows or Ubuntu?

Comment: Boot-Repair, run from a Live USB, sometimes works. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows .If not, I've made a backup image of the drive, reinstalled Ubuntu and then restored the Ubuntu partition.

Comment: @user1574981 - I’d been booting into Linux only for a couple of weeks. There had been plenty of Ubuntu updates but I hadn’t checked for Windows updates for a while.

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippek - that will likely be what I will try in the event a live USB repair doesn’t work. I will comment the outcome.